# Get Data Receiving from a Payment Gateway into the Laravel Application

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, post, payment-gateway

The Laravel Application is integrated with a payment gateway and when passing values to the payment gateway the application will send a notify_url to the payment gateway. The payment gateway is used this notify_url to send back the status of the payment whether the submitted payment is a success or failure. What I need here is to capture that payment status value.

I created a controller as below.

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class NotifyController extends Controller
{
  public function updateTransaction()
    {
            $status_code = Input::post('status_code');
            Storage::put('payment_status.txt', $status_code);
    }

}
```

Under Route following things are added.

```php
Route::post('notify', 'NotifyController@updateTransaction');
Route::get('notify', function()
{
    return View::make('home');
});
```

After purchasing an item payment_status.txt need to have the status code. But after I executing the above code, there is no file created under Storage/app/ called payment_status.txt. Can somebody please tell me what is the error I'm having here? Help me to find out a way to get the payment status after doing the payment.

**NOTE: I cannot test the payment notification by print/echo methods since notify_url never loads to the browser as it's a server callback.**

Comment: Did you tried with `File` instead of `Storage`? There seems to be no issues with the code..

Comment: Thank you, Saiyan for the response. I tried the normal way as well but it didn't work. That's why I use the Storage thing here. Anyway, no I found the answer to my question. **see below**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying several things, I found the answer to my question. It's a simple answer, I don't know why I didn't think about it very beginning without wasting time. Since it's a server callback, Laravel way coding is not going to work here, because it won't invoke the Laravel engine. So what I did here is, wrote **notify.php** in a **procedural way** and added that page to the server. Then once I did the payment through the payment gateway, things worked nicely by updating **payment_status.txt** with the current payment status.